# Why DA40 got some aircraft variants with gust lock on the left seat and some on the right seat?

Tags: diamond-da40

I noticed that the gust lock position differs for some DA40 aircraft..what are the reasons for such difference in mechanical design?

Comment: Is the mechanical design actually different? I.e. are there actually two different models, one for left and one for right? From the answer below it would appear the lock is ambidextrous and capable of being installed on either control stick.

Answer (score 3):

The AFM indicates that the gust lock must be wrapped once around the stick and the rod engaged with the pedals fully slid back:

[image]
([source](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA40-180/Airplane_Flight_Manual/Basic_Manual/60101e-r9-complete.pdf))

it does ***not*** specify which side it is to be mounted on although the AFM depicts it on the pilots side there is no requirement for it to be mounted there and it fits fine in the [other orientation](https://postimg.cc/pyGwQhF6).

[image]
([source](http://support.diamond-air.at/fileadmin/uploads/files/after_sales_support/DA40-180/Airplane_Flight_Manual/Basic_Manual/60101e-r9-complete.pdf))